# Where can i find ImageNet VID dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, benchmarking, detection, imagenet

ImageNet Large-Scale Visual Recognition Challenge 2015 (ILSVRC2015) introduced a task called object-detection-from-video(VID) with a new dataset.

So I go to the ILSVER2015 website and try to find the dataset.
http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2015/index

But I can't find it .
Could someone tell me where to get that dataset?

Comment: As the link below is dead, the one who still want this dataset could download it in this link:http://bvisionweb1.cs.unc.edu/ilsvrc2015/download-videos-3j16.php. – Huang Yuheng Nov 5 at 6:35

Comment: The link is not working anymore. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the page you mentioned under Object detection from Video you will find *Browse all annotated train/val snippets here.*

I linked it [here](http://bvisionweb1.cs.unc.edu/ilsvrc2015/download-videos-3j16.php) for your convinience.

Other than that you should be able to download everything following this [link](http://image-net.org/download-images).

Comment: This link is unavailable now, is there any way to download VID dataset now?

Comment: would you try again? Keep in mind you need to create a Login first. But you should be promted to do so.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear expression. The link you offered words fine, but the link [*Browse all annotated train/val snippets here*](http://vision.cs.unc.edu/ilsvrc2015/ui/vid) on page http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2015/index is unavailable. @mk18

Comment: As the link above is dead, the one who still want this dataset could download it in [this link](http://bvisionweb1.cs.unc.edu/ilsvrc2015/download-videos-3j16.php).

Comment: @huangbiubiu thanks a lot. I made an edit to accepted answer (pending review)

Comment: A not-very-relevant question. Is there any version of Tiny ImageNet in original size of ImageNet? 256*256 instead of 64*64.

Comment: the links are broken, are there any alternative URLs?